Probability of crossing a lane in exactly $4$ seconds
(This question has been asked here, but no answer has been provided at the moment and my question extends beyond the question asked.)
The question is stated as:

The flow of traffic at certain street corner can sometimes be modelled as a sequence of Bernoulli trails by assuming that the probability of a car passing during any given second is a constant $p$ and that there is no interaction between the passing of cars at different seconds.
If we treat seconds as indivisible time units (trials), the Bernoulli model applies.
Suppose a pedestrian can cross the street only if no car is to pass during the next $3$ seconds.
Find the probability that the pedestrian has to wait for exactly $4$ seconds before starting to cross.

The solution given is:

In the seven seconds for the event, no car must pass in the last three seconds, an event with probability $(1 − p)^3$.
The only occurrence in the first four seconds, for which the pedestrian does not wait the entire four seconds, is to have a car pass in the first second and no other car pass.
This has probability $p(1 − p)^3$.
Thus the probability of waiting exactly four seconds before starting to cross is $[1 − p(1 − p)^3](1 − p)^3$.

My Approach:
The last $3$ seconds should not have had a car pass, so the probability, $(1-p)^3$, explains that part.
About the first 4 seconds, don't we have to remove the cases where either no car passes or no car passes in the 4th second and all other permutations in the first 3 seconds?
Cases should be made:
Case 1: where no car passes in the first 4 seconds, let this be $c_1 = (1-p)^4$.
Case 2: permutations where in the fourth second, no car passes, $p$ for the fourth second and remaining $^3C_2$ cases.
Am I missing something?

The probability that no car must pass in the last $3$ second is $(1-p)^3$
If the person should wait for exactly 4 seconds, then a car must pass at the $4$th second. If not the person will be able to cross the road at the $4$th second since $4,5,6,7$ seconds have no passing of cars.
Also at least one car must pass in the first three seconds, because if not then the person will cross the road in the first second.
$P(\text{at least one car passes in first three second})=1-P(\text{no car passes in first three second})=1-(1-p)^3$
Hence the probability that the person waits for exactly 4 second is
$[1-(1-p)^3]p(1-p)^3$

The "solution given" is wrong. You should check the "Dup Question" where I have given some detailed answer.
When your Case 1 occurs , we can cross at first second itself. Hence that will not work out.
When your Case 2 occurs , your wording is unclear , where you say "the fourth second, no car passes, $p$ for the fourth second" , where no car passes is $(1-p)$
Even with that , it is not enough to check $^3C_2$ : we might have to check $^3C_1$ too , hence that too will not work out.
Over-all , you should check the "Dup Question" to get the details.
